# Join Tables with a unique ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello, I work for a benefits company and I am needing a query that joins three tables of data by employee SSN.  For example,

One table has Employee data only.

```
EmployeeSSN SSN            Status      FirstName   LastName
111-11-1111 111-11-1111    Employee    John        Smith
222-22-2222 222-22-2222    Employee    David       Gonzales
333-33-3333 333-33-3333    Employee    Eric        Moore
```

One table has Dependent Data (Spouse)

```
EmployeeSSN SSN            Status      FirstName   LastName
111-11-1111 777-77-7777    Spouse      Dina        Smith
222-22-2222 888-88-8888    Spouse      Niki        Gonzales
333-33-3333 999-99-9999    Spouse      Carla       Moore
```

One table has Dependent Data (Child)

```
EmployeeSSN SSN            Status     FirstName    LastName
111-11-1111 444-44-4444    Child         Cindy         Smith 
222-22-2222 555-55-5555    Child         Calob         Gonzales
333-33-3333 666-66-6666    Child         Kevin         Moore
```

What I need is something that looks like this as the final output (below). The `EmployeeSSN` is what ties the Employee and Dependents together.  I have tried joint statements and pivot statements, still learning SQL, so ran into a lot of issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
EmployeeSSN     SSN          Relation   Last Name     First Name
111-11-1111    111-11-1111   Employee    John           Smith
111-11-1111    777-77-7777   Spouse      Dina           Smith
111-11-1111    444-44-4444   Child       Cindy          ANDRE
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: @user3444754, This is best solution for Search the pivot tables and MySQL. This has nothing to do with UNIONS. Anytime you want to take the value of a column (such as status) and its make those values of the columns - it is a a pivot table. UNION  are used to append rows from one SQL statement to another.

Comment: @user3444754, hey i had some doubts, do you mean the employeessn mean serial no,. and you wants to display the all first value of from all table...

Comment: Have a look here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b04ab/8

Answer (score 0):

try this.......

```
(SELECT EmployeeSSN,SSN,Relation,Last Name,First Name FROM Employee where EmployeeSSN=111-11-1111)
union
(SELECT EmployeeSSN,SSN,Relation,Last Name,First Name FROM Spouse where EmployeeSSN=111-11-1111)
union
(SELECT EmployeeSSN,SSN,Relation,Last Name,First Name FROM Child where EmployeeSSN=111-11-1111)
```

Comment: where did you get the relation, you should must see the table.... its best solution for pivot tables only...

Comment: Looking at the sqlfiddle link I placed above, we have the same thoughts.  :)

Comment: @Leptonator, no where is relation coloumn.

Comment: agreed - it has to be based on EmployeeSSN

Comment: @Leptonator, that was to bad he's showing the output, if maybe he not to display the op, that time your right but not know,....

Answer (score 0):

This works for me..!!!

```
  SELECT EmployeeSSN,SSN,Status As Relation,FirstName,LastName 
  FROM TABLE1 A,TABLE2 B,TABLE3 C where 
  A.EmployeeSSN = B.EmployeeSSN,B.EmployeeSSN = C.EmployeeSSN;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you are looking for:

```
(SELECT EmployeeSSN, SSN, 'Employee' Relation, LastName, FirstName FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeSSN=111-11-1111)
UNION
(SELECT EmployeeSSN, SSN, 'Spouse' Relation, LastName, FirstName FROM SpouseTable EmployeeSSN=111-11-1111) 
UNION
(SELECT EmployeeSSN, SSN, 'Child' Relation, LastName, FirstName FROM DependentTable EmployeeSSN=111-11-1111)
```

Notice that the "Relation" column is being assigned from a string in each of the subqueries. This assigns the proper relation to each record based on its table of origin.